# ServiceStack Authentication C# in Error from JSON Client call

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have created the more than 100 web services without any web security. Now I would like to implement the web security on existing services. So I have started from very basic authentication (Basic / Custom Credentials) by the link below:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#oauth2-providers.

But I am not able to Authenticate the service stack web service from JSON client while testing. I have just created the very basic web security by “CredentialsAuthProvider”. It always return  the error

```
"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
```

I have tried by Basic as well as CustomeCredentials authentication. I do not know where I am doming mistake.

It’s running fine if I executed directly from browser (Firefox or chrome) URL as below

```
1st time execute for authentication  :

    http://192.168.1.120/PatientMeasurementDatabase/auth/credentials?Username=john&Password=test
```

Output :

```
    Session Id  uWv4e9BpSUwScur7KxD6
    User Name  John
    Response Status
```

2nd time execute :

```
    http://192.168.1.120/PatientMeasurementDatabase/GetActiveUserId/
```

Output is OK :

```
    GetActiveUserId
    kpugj_01_07_2015_12_44_23
    isiqz_01_07_2015_12_49_08 
    jjrma_01_07_2015_13_48_56
```

----------- Servicestack webservice ApplicationHost.cs  --------

```
    public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
        {
            public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService,
            string userName, string password)
            {
                return userName == "john" && password == "test";
            }
        }

    public class ApplicationHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// This default constructor passes the name of our service “PersonService” as
            /// well as all assemblies that need to be loaded – in this case we only need to
            /// use the current assembly so I have passed that using typeof()
            /// </summary>
            public ApplicationHost()
            : base("Patient Measurement Database", typeof(ApplicationHost).Assembly)
        {

        }

public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            string database_path = Common.getDatabaseConnectionString();

            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(database_path, MySqlDialectProvider.Instance));

            using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
            {
                CreateTables(db);
            }

            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature()); //Enable CORS

            Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());

            // register storage for user sessions 
            container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
            container.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => 
                                                new SessionFactory(
                                                c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));

            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization"));

            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => 
                new AuthUserSession(), new AuthProvider[] 
               {  
                  new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(), 
               }));
       }
```

------------------------------- SERVICES CLASS -----------------

```
    [Authenticate]
        [Route("/GetActiveUserId ", "GET, POST")]
        public class GetActiveUserId
        {
        }

       public List<GetActiveUserId > Any(GetActiveUserId  request)
            {
            try
            {
                CRUDFunctions objCRUDFunctions = new CRUDFunctions(Db);
                var record = objCRUDFunctions.GetActiveUserId();
                return record;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                return null;
            }
        }
```

---------------------------- Client Side code for GET/POST request to Servicestack server  as below.

```
              try
                {
      string URL = ("http://192.168.1.120/MeasurementDatabase/json/reply/GetActiveUserId"

      WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URL);
                    //WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(address);
                    CredentialCache ch = new CredentialCache();
                    string UserId =  "john";
                    string Password = "test";
                    string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", UserId, Password);
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials);
                    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    string authorization = String.Concat("Credentials ", base64);
                    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);

                    req.Method = "POST";
                    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
                    byte[] bytearray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
                    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                    req.ContentType = "application/json";
                    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                    req.ContentLength = bytearray.Length;
                   WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                   string str = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
      resp.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [C#/.NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) to easily consume authenticated Services.

If you're using a `CredentialsAuthProvider` you can Authenticate with:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);

var authResponse = client.Post(new Authenticate {
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name, //= credentials
    UserName = "test@gmail.com",
    Password = "p@55w0rd",
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

After you successfully authenticate the Service Client `client` instance will be populated with authenticated session cookies which then allows calling Authenticated services, e.g:

```
var response = client.Get(new GetActiveUserId());
```

If you've also registered the `BasicAuthProvider` it will enable your Services to accept [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) which is built-in the Service Clients that you can populate on the Service Client with:

```
client.UserName = "test@gmail.com";
client.Password = "p@55w0rd";
```

Which will also let you access protected Services, e.g:

```
var response = client.Get(new GetActiveUserId());
```

Although behind-the-scenes it ends up making 2 requests, 1st request sends a normal request which will get rejected with a `401 Unauthorized` and if the Server indicates it has the `BasicAuthProvider` enabled it will resend the request with the HTTP Basic Auth credentials.

You could instead save the latency of the additional auth challenge request by specifying the client should always send the Basic Auth with every request:

```
client.AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true;
```